# Why does my van battery have three terminals, and how can I replace it?

Tags: battery, gmc

The battery in our (converted) 1991 GMC G2500 Vandura has a battery with three terminals, which I believe is now dead (reads half a volt with multimeter).  I'm guessing the second positive terminal is for the interior lights and so forth?

We actually have a lithium ion GoalZero Yeti 1000 which we use as a house battery (cooking, heater, extra lights, etc). I've always been meaning to rewire our interior lights to the house battery so that we can run them all night without killing the starter battery.

Can I just replace this battery with a more conventional two terminal battery and wire what was previously connected to the other terminal to the house battery?[image]

Comment: That battery has 4 terminals, one of them has a cover on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do a search for a 78DT battery as on the label on your battery, you will find that it is a dual terminal battery. It has 4 poles, but one of the top ones in your photo has a cap on it.

If the cables on your vehicle will reach to the top poles of the existing battery, then you should be able to replace it with a ‘normal’ 2 pole battery with suitable adaptors for the connectors.

You will obviously need to add the wire that is currently connected to the top to the other positive connector.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to the best thing I could tell you is like a boat that has two batteries in it generally put in a battery switch so you can switch between either one so that in case you killed one battery you could switch to the other one to start and then turn it back to all the charge on as you run the vehicle you have it on all when you stop to run lights and you're not running any charging system on it you switch the switch to either battery one or battery two by itself so just in case you kill the battery you can always switch it to the other one to start your vehicle and charge the system